# 3SUM, but duplicates allowed

Tags: arrays, algorithm, indexing, language-agnostic, combinations

I am trying to solve the [3SUM Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM), but duplicate triplets are allowed. For example, suppose we have the array [2 0 -1 1 -2 3 3]. Here, the solutions are (2, 0, -2), (0, -1, 1), (-1, -2, 3), and (-1, -2, 3). The solutions can also be considered as (A[0], A[1], A[4]), (A[1], A[2], A[3]), (A[2], A[4], A[5]), and (A[2], A[4], A[6]). The indices must be a unique combination, but if they are same values it is fine.

After reading about the problem I found many solutions on AVOIDING duplicates, but none on not keeping them. How would I implement the problem while not avoiding duplicates?

I'm looking for either an O(N^2) solution or an O(N^2logN) solution (not brute force!)

Comment: This might be more something for https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Did you mean `(-1, -2, 3)` instead of `(1, -2, 3)`?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen, yes I did, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: If you want to find all possible triplets, a simple O(N^3) solution seems good enough. I am saying this because it's hard to get and print all triplets in less time(may be O(n^2 log N)). You could sort the array but you still have to add them to the final list.

Comment: @vivek_23 I added time constraints to the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Sort the array first.
- Make a nested loop.
- Outer loop goes from `0` to `n-2`
- Inner loop goes from `i+1` to `n-1`(here, `i` is iteration variable of outer loop).
- Now, we get a two sum value by adding `i` and `j` indices' values.
- We go for checking `-two_sum` to get a triplet with sum as `0`.
- We do some pre-processing and collect all values and it's indices in a hashmap.
- Now, we can simply do checks for it's existence and add all triplets by iterating through indices stored in map.
- Time Complexity: O(n^2) (excluding addition of triplets loop).

**Snippet:**

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {      
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        Map<Integer,LinkedList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,LinkedList<Integer>>();

        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;++i){
            if(!map.containsKey(nums[i])) map.put(nums[i],new LinkedList<Integer>());
            map.get(nums[i]).add(i);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<nums.length-2;++i){
           map.get(nums[i]).poll();
            for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length-1;++j){
               map.get(nums[j]).poll();
               int search_value = -(nums[i] + nums[j]);
               if(map.containsKey(search_value) && map.get(search_value).size() > 0){
                   int start_index = map.get(search_value).peek();
                   int end_index = map.get(search_value).peekLast();
                   for(int k = start_index;k <= end_index;++k) res.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i],nums[j],nums[k])); // add all triplets
               }
            }

            // restore all popped items
            for(int j=nums.length-2;j>i;--j){
                map.get(nums[j]).addFirst(j);
            }

            if(map.get(nums[i]).size() == 0) map.remove(nums[i]);
        }        

        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        List<List<Integer>> triplets = threeSum(new int[]{2,0,-1,1,-2,3,3});
        for(int i=0;i<triplets.size();++i) System.out.println(triplets.get(i).toString());
    }

}
```

**Demo:** https://onlinegdb.com/SJ4ALZ7bL

Comment: Note: The time complexity is the same as the [best time complexity for 3-sum](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem).

Comment: @Yonlif Yes, the time complexity is a bit more than O(N^2) because here we accommodating all triplets rather than just deciding it there exists a sum. Hence, I said excluding triplets  loop to store the results.

Comment: @vivek_23 your solution works! what do you think the total complexity would be (no more than O(n^2logn?))

Comment: @cracra That should be on a lot of average cases, but worst case seems to me as O(n^3) when all elements of the array are 0.